# Validation & Validation Rules for Web Services

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, validation, domain-driven-design

I have experienced the following scenario in most web service apps I've worked on:

1. We **create a Domain Model** (in C#). This is the heart of the application. The Domain Model contains business and validation rules, that determine under what conditions an entity is valid or not.
2. We **create a "web service" layer** (in C#/WCF). **This layer defines DTO-like objects, that are exposed by the web services.** The DTO-like objects are sliced and assembled from pieces of the domain entities, usually in a coarse grained way.
3. **On the web client (JavaScript & HTML) the validation rules are duplicated** in a different format, usually some form of JavaScript validation.

How can the validation rules attached to the pieces of domain entities, be exposed to the client, through the web services? The reason for this is that the domain model's validation rules should be defined once, and then be available to consumer clients in some format throughout the rest of the system.

*The only solution I've come up with so far is to make the validation rules from the domain, available in some form of metadata, defined in XML, JSON, or similar. The big problem with this is that schema between the service layer's DTOs and the domain entities are different, and therefore the domain's validation rules can't be directly sent to the web client - the client works with a different schema, and the domain model.*

Therefore my question is: **What is the approach requiring the least amount of manual and duplicated code, that maps between the different schemas and layers in the application, but allow everything to interpret the validation rules?**

Comment: Why not just serialise your domain objects rather than creating different DTOs that have different validation rules?  Unless you want to change your domain objects but leave the service layer the same i can't see what this transform is adding.

Comment: There are numerous reasons for defining service DTOs. UI clients using the service has different schema requirements, than the domain. In REST, you will be defining and transferring REST-resources. Domain entities have a lot of things attached to them, that has no meaning to service clients. It is inline with SOA best practices ... etc. etc.

Comment: Interesting, I would consider the service layer the hart of the application because it defines the exposed information and available functions.Sorry, but I don't have the answer to your question. I first thought of OCL (Object constraint language), but that's something I've only heard of.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Business Rules:

> Application Specific Rules
>
> Domain Specific Rules.

How you divide rules between the two is another story, but there is no reason why you cannot have duplicated checks.

For example I use a ViewModel in my Web Application which is decorated with Validation Attributes facilitating Unobstrusive Client-Side Validation through jQuery.

I use AutoMapper to convert the Domain Object to the ViewModel and vice-versa.

Having the separate ViewModel allows me to extend the Domain Validation of mandatory fields, with some Application specific checks (where this is possible through Validation Attributes).

Comment: Please explain, for example, how you would get your client and service layer to know that there is a FirstNameMandatoryValidatioRule defined on your Person domain entity, without having to manually redefine/recode it on your ViewModel?

In other words, ideally I'm looking for a solution where I can update the FirstNameMandatoryValidationRule in the domain, and the service DTOs, and web client should be able to automatically know that whatever that field is called in its schema, is mandatory. Validation rules should only be defined once, the rest of the system should just interpret it.

Comment: Also the web client (ViewModel in your case), should be able to perform the validation locally, without calling to the service and domain.

Comment: "Validation rules should only be defined once, the rest of the system should just interpret it." I disagree with that statement. Validation in your Domain Layer should be policing, not dictating. Where potential exists for reuse, then it should be considered - e.g. Binding in the UI to exposed Domain Objects, rather than DTO's, but TBH this is so limiting in other ways, that mostly it's not worth it. There are probably other opinions here, and I accept I have not given you the answer you were seeking - just food for thought maybe.

Comment: The Web Client should perform validation locally. This is then double checked within the webservice which fronts the database (The Web App has no direct connections to a db - only to WCF services). The Web App has to validate itself for performance reasons. The WCF service also has to validate since this is it's raison-d'etre - to protect the validity of the data.

Comment: Note - article advising against binding directly to the domain object - http://www.codethinked.com/aspnet-mvc-think-before-you-bind

Comment: One other thing to think about - if you're still not convinced: Let's say you successfully find a method for achieving what you are trying to do. Then you are asked to build another client to the Service with different requirements, and the validation isn't the same. How would you manage this? Would you have the validation still performed within the service, but make it context sensitive - i.e. aware of who is using it and what validation should be applied? Or would you leave it to the client to TELL the service which particular bits of validation it should be doing?

Comment: BonyT. Thank you for your detailed discussion. 
Definitely food for thought.

Just to make sure eveyone understands. I do not want to _bind_ to the domain. I want the domain to be able to **express*** its business rules related to the validity of its entities. I want different UI clients to be able to _understand_ these rules, and translate them into a format it can understand.

The important thing is that the rules should be defined _once_ & the different client objects (UI and web services) using the domain model, should be able to understand and translate the rules.